# Error after running rake gems:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to install the fedena school management system. When I type `rake gems:install` I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
(in /var/www/html/fedena)
rake aborted!
undefined method `name' for "Ascii85":String

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What shoud I do?

Comment: Start by executing it with `--trace` at the end as suggested :)

Answer (score 1):

For fedena rake 0.8.7 Required So Open command Prompt
type gem install rake v-0.8.7